# practicing paintComponent method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent

I want to practice paintComponent method. My program is consist of two classes(test and paintClass) in different files. I want to divide the area into 25 squares by drawing lines vertically and horizontally by using paintComponent method. My constructor only has paintComponent now. I know it is not very efficient but I will add buttons, labels and other things in the future so I need to use the program like this. When I run the program I get a nullpointerexception error.Can you help?

EDIT : I changed the page into g and added some lines into code. Still has the same error.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        paintClass paint = new paintClass();//This line has error.
        paint.repaint();//ADDED
        frame.add(paint);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class paintClass extends JPanel
{
    private Graphics g;
    private int interval,side,number;

    public paintClass() 
    {
        this.repaint();//ADDED
        paintComponent(g);//This line has error.
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);//ADDED and has an error.
        this.repaint();//ADDED
        side = 250;
        number = 5;
        interval = side / number;
        g.drawRect(0,0, side, side);

        for(int i = 0; i <= number - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= number - 1; j++)
            {
                 g.drawLine(i * interval, 0, i * interval, side);
            }
            g.drawLine(0, i * interval, side, i * interval);
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: `I want to practice paintComponent method.` - then start with the working examples from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). The tutorial will show you a better structure for you program. All you need to change is the code in the paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling paintComponent in the paintClass's constructor with a Graphics object that has not been instantiated. For simple drawing, you shouldn't need to call this method directly - it will be called by the EDT (with the appropriate Graphics object) when necessary (in other words, remove that line and don't hold onto a reference to the Graphics object).

```
//constructor of Class - note Classnames should start with uppercase
public paintClass(){
    //no need to call paintComponent or repaint here
}
```

You can request a repaint by calling the repaint() method defined by JComponent (the parent class of JPanel). You should also call the parent method

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //do your custom drawing here, and never call repaint from this method
}
```

I would recommend, if you have not yet, is to study the Oracle tutorials about Custom painting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: Can only guess what changes you made. You will have to show us the code (eg update your question with the changes made)

Answer (score 1):

First rule of painting in Swing, you don't control the paint process. Swing will paint when and if it wants. The best you can do is provide hints to the system that you would like something updated.

- Never maintain a reference to a Graphics or to you didn't create yourself
- Never call `repaint` directly or indirectly from inside any paint method, this will set up a recursive paint cycle which will eventually consume your CPU
- It's pointless to call `repaint` on a component which isn't displayable on the screen

For example

```
public class paintClass extends JPanel
{

    private int interval,side,number;

    public paintClass() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        side = 250;
        number = 5;
        interval = side / number;
        g.drawRect(0,0, side, side);

        for(int i = 0; i <= number - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= number - 1; j++)
            {
                 g.drawLine(i * interval, 0, i * interval, side);
            }
            g.drawLine(0, i * interval, side, i * interval);
        }

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Override` the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` not to create one. Also, if you want the `paintComponent(...)` to be executed, call `repaint()` on that component, do not call `paintComponent(...)` directly.

Comment: how can I use repaint() method on paintComponent?

Comment: @hackerboy to execute the `paintComponent(...)` you can do this `paint.repaint()` where `paint` is an instance of `paintClass`, also you can call `this.repaint()` inside any method of `paintClass`.

Answer (score -2):

In your class "paintClass", you should instantiate the page var :

```
public paintClass() 
{
    page = new Graphics();
    paintComponent(page);
}
```

Comment: It gives the following error :error: Graphics is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: The Graphics class is abstract. One should rely on the appropriate Graphics context, in this case the one passed to paintComponent when the method is called by the EDT.